# Process Date Regex Capturing Groups outputs in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, regex-group

I'm trying to coerce dates from two formats into a single one that I can easily feed into `as.Date`. Here's a sample:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(date = c("Mar 29 2017 9:30AM", "5/4/2016"))
```

I've tried this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(date = gsub("([A-z]{3}) (\\d{2}) (\\d{4}).*", 
                     paste0(which(month.abb == "\\1"),"/\\2","/\\3"), date))
```

But it gave me this:

```
      date
1 /29/2017
2 5/4/2016
```

but I want this!

```
      date
1 3/29/2017
2 5/4/2016
```

It looks like when I use `month.abb == "\\1"`, it doesn't use the capturing group output (`"Mar"`), it just uses the caller text (`"\\1"`). I want to do this in regex if possible. I know you can do it another way but want to be slick.

Any ideas?

Comment: `as.Date` can take two formats, i.e. `as.Date(df$date, format = c('%b %d %Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y'))` (untested)

Comment: I want to do it with regex. Thanks though.

Comment: As explanation: regex sees the result of the paste0  expression -- it never sees the values that go into  the paste expression.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Looks like there is no way to convert `"Mar"` to `3` in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
df$date <- gsubfn("^([A-Za-z]{3})\\s+(\\d{2})\\s+(\\d{4}).*", function(x, y, z) 
                  paste(match(x, month.abb),y, z, sep="/"), df$date)
df$date
#[1] "3/29/2017" "5/4/2016"
```

---

Or `sub` in combination with `gsubfn`

```
sub("(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+).*", "\\1/\\2/\\3", 
      gsubfn("^([A-z]{3})", setNames(as.list(1:12), month.abb), df$date))
#[1] "3/29/2017" "5/4/2016"
```